# How to change the value of a Bootstrap progress bar using PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

How can we change the value of Bootstrap progress bar by using PHP variables?
Here is my code so far:

```
 <?php                 
 $total_prize=360000;
 $paid_amount=160000;
 echo "
      <div class='progress'>
           <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='$paid_amount' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='$total_prize' style='width:$paid_amount%;'>
            </div>
      </div>
 ";
 ?>
```

Comment: what is the issue???

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php ?

Comment: You're making it too difficult on yourself with a question like that, its [basic math](https://www.google.nl/search?q=how+to+calculate+percentage).

Comment: value of progress bar not increasing. i am new in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$total_prize=360000;
$paid_amount=260000;
$width = round(($paid_amount/$total_prize)*100,2);

echo '<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'.$width.'"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="'.$total_prize.'" style="width:'.$width.'%">
    '.$width.'% Complete 
  </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: why you give 2 at the end of width estatment

Comment: @SoorajAbbasi I used that for round number to two decimals(example: 75.56989 to 75.57)